# Google Machine Learning Engine Python 3

Tags: google-cloud-ml

the latest runtime version 1.4 of the Google machine learning engine supports Python 3.5:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list

How do I use Python 3.5 for training models in the ML engine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The python_version works for me. Please note that python_version is a string. And also it only works with 1.4 runtime version.

trainingInput:
  pythonVersion: '3.5'
  scaleTier: BASIC

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field [pythonVersion](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#TrainingInput) as 3.5 in the TrainingInput. If you use gCloud, you can pass this flag in a [yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview) and specify the flag --config=config.yaml assuming config.yaml is your yaml file name.

Comment: I put `pythonVersion: 3.5` in my config.yml and now get the following error response `ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "python_version" at 'job': Cannot find field.`

Comment: please use pythonVersion instead python_version in yaml file as Jiaxun suggested above